# Cors problem with stripe payment in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, stripe-payments

I have a problem with Stripe payments in Angular and nodeJS.
I'm getting an error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh3sO.png);

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1GABMpi' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In stripe docs theres no solution for angular application.
Here's my current code.

**Backend (node.js)**

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const colors = require('colors');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/error');
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' });
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY);

connectDB();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use(
  cors({
    origin: '*',
  })
);

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY);
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price: process.env.STRIPE_PRICE,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `https://google.com`,
    cancel_url: `https://google.com`,
    automatic_tax: { enabled: true },
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  );
});
```

**Frontend (Angular)**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PaymentService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  startPayment() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    });

    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:5000/create-checkout-session', {}, { headers })
      .subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
  }
}
```

Whats wrong with this code? I tried many options found in the web and stripe docs and still cant find any solution.

Comment: The issue is likely using `http.post()` to perform server redirect. Can you try returning the [`url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url) of the Checkout Session to the client and perform redirection at the client instead of performing server redirect?

Comment: Redirecting and payment working now. I have one more question. I m using stripe payment to adding creadits to wallet on my app. After redirecting to stripe page the user selects the amount he wants to deposit. How can i get this amount after succesfull payment?